# Xcode 4 Cmd+alt+up/down remapping

Tags: xcode4

I realise that switching between header and implementation files has moved to ctrl+cmd+up/down.

however this is incredibly annoying, as there is no Ctrl button near the arrow keys, before I could do it quickly with 3 fingers on one hand.

So i opened up preferences found that I could change the key bindings and attempted to press cmd+alt+up/down. However it seems that it is the only box that refuses to accept the alt key. I tried any combination of alt+any key, and it just entered the key without alt. How can I bypass this? Is there a manual way of setting key bindings, and why on earth is alt not allowed in these 2 particular key bindings?

Comment: this is also driving me nuts, because ctrl+cmd+up is how I move up a Space >.<

Comment: The other annoying change is pressing enter on code completion just inserts a line break, and doesn't complete the code like it did in xcode 3.

Comment: The problem with the Enter key, dissapeared shortly. But still it's irritating the CMD+alt+up can't be remapped. However a new feature (?) of Xcode 4 means that if you hold down CMD and click on a class/method name it will take you to the definition of that class/method

Comment: I`m trying to press Ctrl+cmd+up and nothing happens!

Comment: Holy crap is this bug pissing me off - I use a non-standard RSI keyboard, and having it be cmd+ctrl is NOT usable - thanks for asking this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I reported a bug at apple. (Problem ID: 9125898)

Please add any details there.. [edit] oops, not possible.. Just submit another one :)

Comment: well, it seems like you couldn't anyway add details to the bug i submitted. On the apple site Bugs are personal and you cannot see bugs submitted by others.. You cannot even see if your bug has already been submitted.. I imagine the meeting at apple deciding about the visibility of bugs: "Hide them!" - "but.." - "HIDE THEM. Meeting is closed." - "ok.." LOL

Comment: lol, did you include the problem with Enter not working in code completion as well (it is documented to provide a slightly different function than TAB)

Comment: for me the enter key seems to work in the same way of the tab key. it don't inserts a line break. What slightly different behavior are you referring to? i couldn't find anything in the documentation..

Comment: When you select a code completion item using the arrow keys it puts it in the grey text after the caret. If you press TAB it will complete sections of the grey text, but if you press Enter it should complete the whole grey text in one go. I found this definition in Xcode 4 Transition guide.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's a bug but YES you can remap it. However the behavior is a little different from that in Xcode 3. You can set it to **Cmd+alt+up** /**down** in Preferences. Note that you can't set the **alt** key on "Jump to Next Counterpart" but only "Jump to Next Counterpart (option)".
[image: Jump to Next Counterpart (option)]
This new key binding will open implementation/interface file in Assistant Editor side-by-side with the original editor.

**Cmd+Return** to close the Assistant Editor.

Comment: Yes I know but that is the problem, I don't want to open it in assistant editor. I should be able to set **my** key bindings to how **I** like them, even if apple doesn't like. Currently I've set it to an obscure combination and used Keyboard Maestro to rerebind it to CMD+alt+up/down, not as elegant but it works.