# Xcode 4 - changing a shortcut

Tags: iphone, xcode

First I would like to say that I hate Xcode 4 with passion. It is obtrusive and not friendly.

Said that, after upgrading to the new release of 4.2, one of my shortcuts stopped working and it is refusing to let me change it again.

The shortcut was ⌥ ⌘ ⬆

Every time I pressed this, a new window opened (if not opened yet), showing me the counter part file (.m or .h). Now, this is disabled.

Now, there are only 3 options on the key bindings window, all assigned to other shortcuts and none does what I want. The closer is the second one: Jump to Next Counterpart (option) but this splits the window and opens the counterpart on the right half of the window and the shortcut cannot be changed (it is grayed out and locked).

How do I solve that?

This is the screenshot of the bindings panel filtering for "jump"

[image]

Comment: Could you give us a screenshot of the key bindings window please?

Comment: I have posted a screenshot. Thanks.

Comment: +1 for disliking 4. Not all is bad but for me it's not a step forward but slighlty a step back. They messed up the shortcuts and it was a problem from the beginning s. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282236/xcode-4-cmdaltup-down-remapping

Comment: I used to hate 4 as well, but after becoming familiar with it, I like it a lot more than I did 3.  It just takes a bit of a transition period to get acquainted with where things are and the new options available.  As for your problem, there are two options that I know of, though neither are shortcut bindings.  The first is just to use the navigation line above your code to select the counterpart file.  The second, which I personally use, is using Editor.  Select the middle option and tell it to use Counterparts, then you can see the files side-by-side

Comment: @Kay I would say 100 lightyears back. No separate debugger window, everything hidden in menus inside menus, no way to order the files you drag on the project, etc., the list goes on and one.

Comment: @slev I am 90% familiar with it but I still hate it with all my powers. The debugger,for example, a truly important part of the project is a tiny 100 x 100 pixels box in the lower corner of the window. I know I can expand that, but the guy who designed probably did under the influence of LSD or some heavy drug. For God's sake!

Comment: @kay the page you suggested did not solve my problem. Sorry. This is strange because I had this working with the last build of Xcode 4.2. This is the iOS 5 GM Xcode version.

Comment: Haha, I can certainly understand you with the debugger.  Scrolling through that tiny section to search your log statements is a pain in the ass.  Sorry I can't be more help getting the shortcuts back to how they were, though.  Like I said, I just use Editor to work on both files at once.  But if I find anything regarding reassigning hotkeys, I will be sure to pass it on to you

Comment: @slev thanks. To amuse me, meanwhile I will entertain myself banging my head in the wall with another insane error of Xcode 4.2 that I am having right now... :(